# I get this error System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: when executing my api on .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

Currently I have a problem executing my ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API and that I merged through git with respect to other branches

This error started to appear when trying to execute my project again and I would like to know what could be the cause of this:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The requested address is not valid in this context.'

And this happens on the following line of code:

```
app.Run();
```

The details of the error are as follows:

> This exception was originally thrown on this call stack:
>
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, string)
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Net.Internals.SocketAddress)
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(System.Net.EndPoint)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(System.Net.EndPoint, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionDelegate, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.EndpointConfig, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)

Comment: It seems that port already in use. check the port specified in launchsetting.json file and also if the any other process is running on same port.